# Run PHP function with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I was going to run `krimaction1`,  a PH function when the JavaScript runs, but I've not had any luck solving this and I'm not really good at JS. How can I run that PHP function in the JavaScript?

Here is the code I've tried so far

```
<?php

function krimaction1() {
    echo"IT IS ALIVE!";
}

?>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#krim_1').click(function(){
            alert(this.id);
            var myTD = this.id.split('_')[1];
            var newFrm = '<form id="myNewForm1"><input name="newdata" value="' +myTD+ '" /></form>';
            $('body').append(newFrm);
            $('#myNewForm').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've tried another method with this as my JS:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("ThisIsTheValue").value = "Johnny Bravo";
    document.getElementById("SubmitForm").click();
}
```

but that code doesn't work either for me, as when I try to set the value with the JS and click it it doesn't do anything and I can't really see what's wrong.

Comment: Javascript run at client side and PHP run on server side.this is not possible

Comment: as Minesh said it's impossible to run php function from javascript. But write, what you want to achieve. There can be other solutions.

Comment: If the action of myNewForm is the php page itself, then you can add `<?PHP if (isset($_GET["newdata"])) { krimaction1() } ?>`

Comment: is it possible to make it just post some data to the page like i can grab it whit $_POST["SOMENAME"]; and that post returns like 1 if it is posted and zero if not?

Comment: Judging by the comments, this question is not a duplicate of the posted link

Comment: Ive updated the question whit a new method ive tried.

Comment: You need to update your question with the relevant HTML and code. You have now switched from jQuery to plain JS and not shown where you call the myFunction

Answer (score 1):

It seems the action of myNewForm is the php page itself, so you can add

```
<?PHP 
  function krimaction1() {
   echo "IT IS ALIVE!";
  }

  if (isset($_GET["newdata"])) { krimaction1(); } 
?>
```

to the page to have it execute when the form is submitted

I use $_GET here since that is the default for the form you have created.

If you do NOT want to reload the page to see IT IS ALIVE, you need to AJAX the result